# How to prove the continuity?

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Prove that the function :
$f(x) = x$ when $x$ is rational and
$f(x) = 1 - x$ when $x$ is irrational
is continuous at $x = \frac{1}{2}$

To prove the continuity
it is necessary to prove that for every $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta$ such that
$|f(x) - f(\frac{1}{2})| < \epsilon$
whenever $|x -c| < \delta$ $- (1)$
Now if we choose $a  \in (\frac{1}{2} - \delta, \frac{1}{2} + \delta)$ and also $a $ is rational and choose $\epsilon < |a - \frac{1}{2}|$ then condition in $(1)$ is not satisfied.
How to move from here?

Comment: Unfinished and overkill but I thought it was interesting. We can show by comparing to the Dirichlet function that $f(x)=\lim_k\lim_j [\underbrace{x+\left(1-2x\right)\cos\left(k!\pi x\right)^{2j}}_{g}]$. So since $g$ is continuous and strictly decreasing in an interval around $\frac12$ for all $j$, $k$, we should have continuity of $f$ at $\frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

You can't choose $\epsilon$ after choosing $\delta$. A $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof is like a game between two players. Player A chooses an $\epsilon$, and player $B$ finds a $\delta$ so that the $f(x)$ stays within $\epsilon$ of the $f(a)$ whenever $x$ is within $\delta$ of $a$. If the function is continuous, then Player A can choose smaller and smaller $\epsilon$'s, and Player B will always be able to find a $\delta$ that works. If the function is not continuous, then Player A can find an $\epsilon$ so that no choice of $\delta$ works for Player B.

In your attempted proof Player A has "cheated" by shrinking their $\epsilon$ after $\delta$ was chosen. Instead, you should start with a fixed $\epsilon>0$, and then show that there is a $\delta>0$ so that if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$|x-1/2|=|(1-x)-1/2|$$

Therefore given a positive $\epsilon $ , let $\delta =\epsilon$ and proceed.